# How to write a test in Kotlin that will just open and then close an app

Tags: kotlin

Im new to Android studio and I want to write a test in Kotlin that will just open an application and then close it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what do you mean with this? Just open app which contains nothing and than close? I do not understand your idea... If you explain more, I will try

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear. Im trying to run a test on some completed applications that will test if the app launches. Some of the apps will crash when loaded on a device.so im just trying to write a simple test that launches the app if it opens it passes if it does not it fails.The applications were written in Kotlin which I have no experience in. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: If there is many apps I am not sure how you can check them automatically... If you check by hand, you can just install that apps and look if that apps work correctly - if there is an error, you can open "logcat" inside of android studio and see in which line of code error appears

Comment: I need to do it as a test because it needs to be a part of the build process. When the app gets built it needs to test if can open on a device if not the build should fail.